# How to select a row with a MDB database (TDBGrid)

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

I was hoping someone could assist me. I know how to display a column but only for the selected row, not sure how to select a row.

I have a small MDB 3x9

```
Item    Supplier    Price
--------------------------    
apple   applesRus   $1
Grape   GrapesRus   $2
Milk    MilkRus     $3
....    ....        ...
```

just want to know the suppliers (Just a rough draft)

```
for supplierList < 9 do;
begin
supplierlist + 1;
supplier : = DBgrid1.row[supplierlist].field[1];
memo1.Lines.Add(Supplier);
end;
```

Comment: Move the cursor of the underlying dataset object (e.g. by the `Locate` method).

Comment: I think what you're looking for is "dataset.next", not really clear though. OTH you'd want a "while not dataset.eof do ... " loop rather than a "for" loop.

Answer (score 0):

How to go about this depends on whether your grid has dgMultiSelect in the `Options` property
set to true or false.

If dgMultiSelect is False, it is simply a matter of looking up the field value of the
current row of the dataset supplying the DBGrid, because the record shown as selected in the DBGrid is the one the dataset's logical cursor is positioned on.  You can do that with something like

```
  Memo1.Lines.Add(DataSet.FieldByName('Supplier').AsString);
```

If dgMultiSelect is True, you need need to utilize the fact that the rows selected in
the DBGrid are recorded in a `TBookmarkList` accessible via the grid's SelectedRows property.
Basically, you iterate the SelectedRows, use each bookmark to visit the corresponding row
in the dataset and look up the field value.  Something like

```
  ADataSet := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet;

  for i:=0 to DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count-1 do begin
    ADataSet.GotoBookmark(pointer(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Items[i]));
    Memo1.Lines.Add(DataSet.FieldByName('Supplier').AsString);
  end;
```

When operating one multiple records, it is better, performance-wise, to:

- bracket the operations between calls to DisableControls and EnableControls
  on the dataset, using `try ..finally ...`

and

- assign the result of ADataSet.FieldByName(somename) to a local TField variable
  and look up the field value from that.